# Casting SimpeInjectorWebApiDependencyRresolver to IDependencResolver

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'm working on an ASP.Net web API project. Recently I've tried to refactor my solution and moving all the code relating to dependency injection to a separate project. I use Simple Injector Integration library as dependency injection solution. 
There is an IDependencyResolver interface in System.Web.Http.Dependencies which is implemented by SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencResolver. 
I created a class named ResolutionProvider which is supposed to provide a proper dependency resolver object for GlobalConfiguratiuon.Configuration.DependencyResolver field. The ResolutionProvider class has a method with the following signature and body:

```
public IDependencyResolver GetResolver()
{
    return new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(_container);
}
```

The problem is : 
However SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver implements IDependencyResolver, I'm getting a compile-time error:
Cannot convert expression type  SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver to retun type IDependencyResolver.
I have tried to cast the class to its interface without no success.

Question:
  What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a very good look at the compile error. The most likely cause is that the `IDependencyResolver` that your method returns is the `System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver` and not the `System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver`.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. It was a conflict in namespaces.